# .htaccess Wordpress Symfony

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony1

I have a Symfony 1.4 project. With standard .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I just want to have in my web symfony folder a Wordpress setup (in fact many, with different languages):

```
-web (folder)
 index.php
 frontend.php
 -blogwordpress
  -fr
     index.php
  -en
     index.php
```

My question is: what should I write on .htaccess file shown before to allow a request like:
http://127.0.0.1/blogwordpress/fr

to be catched up by the Wordpress index.php, and not by the Symfony frontend ?

Of course when I type this url 404 appears on my Symfony:

```
404 | Not Found | sfError404Exception
Action "blogwordpress/fr" does not exist.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this right after the `RewriteEngine On` statement;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?wordpress
```

In layman's terms;

> only apply the following rules if the request does **not** begin with `wordpress`